# how to keep the original image's dpi when downloading an image from the web?

Tags: java, image, save, javax.imageio, dpi

I wrote a short program in Java to download an image from a url. It works fine, except that the dpi is automatically reduced to 90dpi from 300dpi.

Is there a way to keep the original image's dpi? Code below:

```
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class downloader1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

        //Open URL//
        URL url = new URL("url.jpg");

        //Save Image.//
        Image image = null;
        image = ImageIO.read(url);

        try {
            ImageIO.write((RenderedImage) image, "jpg", new File("image4.jpg"));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
        }

    }


}
```

Comment: You can simply read bytes using input stream from opened connection of url: `url.openConnection().getInputStream()`. Just read chunks of bytes and write them to `FileOutputSteram`. Anyway to help us help you better share a link we could use to reproduce this behaviour.

Comment: How do you know the dpi is been changed? Do you have a sample image that we might test?

Comment: Thanks! Below is a sample image. The original image is 300dpi. The onw I save with the Java program is 96 (right-click \ properties \ details) http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg

Comment: http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/94/Starry_Night_Over_the_Rhone.jpg

Comment: possible duplicate of [Download file from server in java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872611/download-file-from-server-in-java)

Comment: I'm marking this as a duplicate, as there is no need to use ImageIO to perform your task (as @Pshemo also mentions). To download an image, just download as any other file, as in the linked duplicate.