# How to download .zip file from URL using java

Tags: java

guys!
I have a problem! I'm trying to download a .zip (size is 150 mb) file from Internet using this code:

```
public void downloadBuild(String srcURL, String destPath, int bufferSize, JTextArea debugConsole) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException {
    debugConsole.append(String.format("**********Start process downloading file. URL: %s**********\n", srcURL));
    try {
        URL url = new URL(srcURL);
        HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        httpConn.setRequestMethod("POST");
        httpConn.connect();
        in = httpConn.getInputStream();
        out = new FileOutputStream(destPath);
        byte buffer[] = new byte[bufferSize];
        int c = 0;
        while ((c = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            out.write(buffer, 0, c);
        }
        out.flush();
        debugConsole.append(String.format("**********File. has been dowloaded: Save path is: %s********** \n", destPath));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        debugConsole.append(String.format("**********Error! File was not downloaded. Detail: %s********** \n", e.toString()));
    } finally {
        try {
            if (out != null) {
                out.close();
            }
            if (in != null) {
                in.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException ex) {
        }
    }
}
```

but the file is not completely downloaded. (only 4000 bytes). What am I doing wrong?

Comment: why do you use http post request? use this to download http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18872611/download-file-from-server-in-java

Comment: Not that it solves anything but you shouldn't ignore exceptions. Always at least print their stack-trace.

Comment: But i don't have exception in my program, but file file is not completely downloaded.

Answer (score 3):

you can use the following code to download and extract zip file from given uri path.

```
        URL url = new URL(uriPath);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        InputStream in = connection.getInputStream();
        ZipInputStream zipIn = new ZipInputStream(in);
        ZipEntry entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();

        while(entry != null) {

            System.out.println(entry.getName());
            if (!entry.isDirectory()) {
                // if the entry is a file, extracts it
                System.out.println("===File===");

            } else {
                System.out.println("===Directory===");
            }
            zipIn.closeEntry();
            entry = zipIn.getNextEntry();

        }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
FileOutputStream("example.zip").getChannel().transferFrom(Channels.newChannel(new URL("http://www.example.com/example.zip").openStream()), 0, Long.MAX_VALUE);
```

Simple one-liner. For more info, read [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/channels/ReadableByteChannel.html)

Comment: same answer with one of the comments?

Comment: @KonstantinosChalkias If you feel this question was answered in another post, you should flag this question and mark it as duplicate, specifying which post it's a duplicate of. Other than that, comments are not answers, so this is fine. You should avoid answering questions in the comment section if you feel someone might steal it

Comment: This worked for me..